# Shopping cart rule - free shipping for items combination

Tags: magento-1.7

Could someone please show me how to setup a shopping cart rule so that:
(item A by itself shipping: $5) (item B by itself shipping: $5)

When someone has items A and B in their cart, shipping for (any amount of) item B should be free; total shipping should only be $5 for item A.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fairly close, for your Conditions you want the following:

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
    If total quantity  equals or greater than  1  for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions:
        SKU  contains  PRODUCT_A 
    If total quantity  equals or greater than  1  for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions:
        SKU  contains  PRODUCT_B
```

Then in the Actions tab you want to set Free Shipping to "For Matching Items only".
For the actions cart item conditions you want to set the following:

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
    SKU  contains  PRODUCT_B
```

Note that when doing the SKU rules I'm using the contains comparator, I've found problems with the equals comparator on string comparisons in some magento versions.

Where this may not be right for you is in the scenario when there are multiple item A's.
With this rule your normal shipping costs will still apply as the quantity of item A's increases and I think in your question you want to cap the Item A shipping costs at $5 in total.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best off with a shipping extension.  Amasty has shipping by item, shipping rules, and shipping restriction extensions.  I'm sure one of them will fit the bill.

Benz001 rule would work, but you will need to set flat rate shipping.  With an extension you could simply set a shipping amount per item.